# Sugarcrm installation error in Trixbox

Tags: php, sugarcrm, trixbox

I am installing `sugarcrm` in my `trixbox` but i am getting session.save_path error. I am not sure where i am missing code. Can any one please help me the steps to install `sugarcrm` in my `trixbox.`

SugarCRM relies upon PHP sessions to store important information while connected to this web server. Your PHP installation does not have the Session information correctly configured.

A common misconfiguration is that the 'session.save_path' directive is not pointing to a valid directory.

Please correct your PHP configuration in the php.ini file located here below.

/etc/php.ini

i am getting above error message. Even if i save session.save_path = /tmp i am getting error.

Answer (score -1):

PHP session use filebase as default handler for browser session. `session.save_path` in php.ini indicate where the session data saved in filesystem.
It probably set to a folder apache do not have write permission or that folder does not even exist.

Open your /etc/php.ini and find `session.save_path` and change to appropriate value.